# wine right-click menu too small

Tags: fonts, wine

I am using `wine-4.14` in a `Fedora release 30` machine with a high-resolution screen, and I have some trouble with the font size of menus. For example, if I open `regedit`, the menus in the picture below are very small. For other Windows applications, the problem also exists. Even if I try to adjust "Screen resolution" to a higher dpi value in `winecfg`, the font size in the menu bar is still very small. Is there any way to make the font bigger?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try to rename the default wine prefix folder and restart wine.

Comment: It seems that the problem is due to corrupted `.reg` files in `.wine` directory, which may be caused by an update to my operating system. Once I replaced it with a new one, the problem is solved.